# bug in an HTML/JS incremental game

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating an incremental game, much like cookie clicker. I call it Atom Clicker. It should work like any clicker game, but I cant seen to find a bug.

When I run the code I have, I can get atoms just fine and I can buy the "Molecules" upgrade. Then the bug starts. The molecule upgrade doesn't do anything! I have it set to add in to the `TotalAutoClick` variable at twice the number of molecules you have. then If you try and buy the Element upgrade, nothing happens! If you keep clicking on the "Buy Element" button several more times, the number of elements becomes `NaN`. Then, if you keep clicking on buy element you atoms go down, but the number of element stays `NaN`.

Whats going wrong?

```js
//Getting atoms

var Atoms = 0;

function AtomClick(number) {
  Atoms = Atoms + number;
  document.getElementById("Atoms").innerHTML = Atoms;
};

//First Upgrade - Elements
var Elements = 0;

function buyElement() {
  var ElementCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.3, Elements)); //works out the cost of this Element
  if (Atoms >= ElementCost) { //checks that the player can afford the Element
    Elements = Elements + 1; //increases number of Elements
    Atoms = Atoms - ElementCost; //removes the Atoms spent
    document.getElementById('Elements').innerHTML = Elements; //updates the number of Elements for the user
    document.getElementById('Atoms').innerHTML = Atoms; //updates the number of Atoms for the user
  };
  var nextECost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.3, Element)); //works out the cost of the next Element
  document.getElementById('ElementCost').innerHTML = nextECost; //updates the Element cost for the user
};


//Second Upgrade - Molecules
var Molecules = 0;

function buyMolecule() {
  var MoleculeCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.5, Molecules)); //works out the cost of this Molecule
  if (Atoms >= MoleculeCost) { //checks that the player can afford the Molecule
    Molecules = Molecules + 1; //increases number of Molecules
    Atoms = Atoms - MoleculeCost; //removes the Atoms spent
    document.getElementById('Molecules').innerHTML = Molecules; //updates the number of Molecules for the user
    document.getElementById('Atoms').innerHTML = Atoms; //updates the number of Atoms for the user
  };
  var nextMCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.5, Molecule)); //works out the cost of the next Molecule
  document.getElementById('MoleculeCost').innerHTML = nextMCost; //updates the Molecule cost for the user
};

//Finding auto click

//Molecule APS (Atoms Per Seconds)
var MoleculeAC = Molecules * 2;

//Total aouto click
var AutoClickTotal = Elements + MoleculesAC;





window.setInterval(function() {

  AtomClick(Molecules);

}, 1000);
```

```html
<button onclick="AtomClick(1)">*Image of atom needed*</button>
<br /> Atoms: <span id="Atoms">0</span>
<br />

<button onclick="buyElement()">Buy Element</button>
<br /> Elements: <span id="Element">0</span>
<br /> Element Cost: <span id="ElementCost">10</span>
<br />

<button onclick="buyMolecule()">Buy Molecule</button>
<br /> Molecules: <span id="Molecules">0</span>
<br /> Molecule Cost: <span id="MoleculeCost">100</span>
```

Comment: I get an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: MoleculesAC is not defined"

Comment: I don't know why it is saying that. It is defined in line var MoleculeAC = Molecules * 2

Comment: You define `MoleculeAC`, but not `MoleculesAC`.

Comment: I have fixed that in my code, but the error still happens. p.s. I can’t find the edit button to fix the code in the post. (I am on iPad, haven’t  checked PC yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bugs seem to revolve around inconsistent variable names and element IDs.
To troubleshoot, check your browser console for JavaScript errors.

1. Variable Name: MoleculeAC / MoleculesAC
2. Variable Name: Molecule / Molecules
3. Element ID: Element / Elements

```js
//Getting atoms

var Atoms = 1000;
var Elements = 0;
var Molecules = 0;

function AtomClick(number) {
  Atoms = Atoms + number;
  document.getElementById("Atoms").innerHTML = Atoms;
};

function buyElement() {
  var ElementCost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.3, Elements)); //works out the cost of this Element
  if (Atoms >= ElementCost) { //checks that the player can afford the Element
    Elements++; //increases number of Elements
    Atoms -= ElementCost; //removes the Atoms spent
    document.getElementById('Elements').innerHTML = Elements; //updates the number of Elements for the user
    document.getElementById('Atoms').innerHTML = Atoms; //updates the number of Atoms for the user
  };
  var nextECost = Math.floor(10 * Math.pow(1.3, Elements)); //works out the cost of the next Element
  document.getElementById('ElementCost').innerHTML = nextECost; //updates the Element cost for the user
};


function buyMolecule() {
  var MoleculeCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.5, Molecules)); //works out the cost of this Molecule
  if (Atoms >= MoleculeCost) { //checks that the player can afford the Molecule
    Molecules++; //increases number of Molecules
    Atoms -= MoleculeCost; //removes the Atoms spent
    document.getElementById('Molecules').innerHTML = Molecules; //updates the number of Molecules for the user
    document.getElementById('Atoms').innerHTML = Atoms; //updates the number of Atoms for the user
  };
  var nextMCost = Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.5, Molecules)); //works out the cost of the next Molecule
  document.getElementById('MoleculeCost').innerHTML = nextMCost; //updates the Molecule cost for the user
};



window.setInterval(function() {

  AtomClick(Elements + (Molecules * 2));

}, 1000);
```

```html
<button onclick="AtomClick(1)">*Image of atom needed*</button>
<br> Atoms: <span id="Atoms">1000</span>
<br>

<button onclick="buyElement()">Buy Element</button>
<br> Elements: <span id="Elements">0</span>
<br> Element Cost: <span id="ElementCost">10</span>
<br>

<button onclick="buyMolecule()">Buy Molecule</button>
<br> Molecules: <span id="Molecules">0</span>
<br> Molecule Cost: <span id="MoleculeCost">100</span>
```

Comment: thank you! worked well, but when I substitute the `MoleculesAC` or `AutoClickTotal` variable the auto click stops working. (wouldn't let me edit comment after further testing)

Comment: Both `MoleculesAC` and `AutoClickTotal` are always zero; their values are never updated. I changed the auto-click `setInterval` to use the `Elements` and `Molecules` variables directly.

Comment: thanks. some of the code was not the same as you posted. I think that something might have gotten cut off in the copy. thanks.